# 100% height for a absoulutely positioned child div

Tags: css, navigation, height, css-position

I'm making a navigation where the children will be showed in a different box, much like http://www.boffi.com/EN/Collections/bathrooms/b14.aspx . I managed to separate the child using absolute positioning, but can't get the child elements background to have a 100% height. it's a list element, so if I put height: 100% , the bottom two main navigation elements dissapears. Please help! Here's my html:

```
<ul id="mainmenu">
     <li id="liHome" class="active">
         <a href="#item-x1y1" class="panel" rel="none" id="Home">Home</a>
     </li>
     <li id="liServices" class=" ">
         <a href="#item-x1y2" class="panel" rel="SubMenuY2" id="Services">Services</a>
         <div class="child">
         <ul style="" id="SubMenuY2" class="submenu">
             <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
         </ul>
         </div>
     </li>
     <li id="liEnvironment">
         <a href="#item-x1y3" class="panel" rel="none" id="Environment">Environment</a>
     </li>
     <li id="liCareer">
         <a href="#item-x1y4" class="panel" rel="none" id="Career">Career</a>
     </li>
     <li id="liContact">
         <a href="#item-x1y5" class="panel" rel="none" id="Contact">Contact</a>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

and the css

```
body, html{
height:100%;
}
#mainmenu{
background:black;
color: white;
width:130px;
position:relative;
top:0;
height:100%
}
#mainmenu li a {
color:white;
}

ul.submenu{
position:absolute;
background:blue;
width:130px;
}

div.child{
position:relative;
margin-left:130px;
}
```

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Have you considered just using a table?

Comment: can't use table. it's a wordpress site and the client would prefer to keep the code semantic. thanks though! I thought of it too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I simplified your code a little.. well I actually just removed the `div` with `class="child"`, as you don't really need it.

Then, all I did was this:

```
ul.submenu{
  position:absolute;
  left: 130px; top: 0;
  background:blue;
  width:130px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Take a look at the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/rqqju/

Was this what you were looking for?